# export 'HasError' (imported as 'HasError') was not found in 'vform' (possible exports: Errors, Form, default)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, laravel-mix-vue3

I use the following code below in the app.js, it is not working

```
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)
```

It got error as the picture below
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are importing it from the wrong location.

You can see this [here](https://vform.vercel.app/#form)

```
import {
  Button,
  HasError,
  AlertError,
  AlertErrors,
  AlertSuccess
} from 'vform/src/components/bootstrap5'
// 'vform/src/components/bootstrap4'
// 'vform/src/components/tailwind'

Vue.component(Button.name, Button)
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)
Vue.component(AlertErrors.name, AlertErrors)
Vue.component(AlertSuccess.name, AlertSuccess)
```